# Android Studio, library inside library

Tags: android, facebook, maven, gradle

I build my library named "my_library", in my_library I add facebook-android-sdk as a dependency. Then I create the project named "my_project" with my_library is a dependency. In my_project, I cannot access facebook-android-sdk library though it was included in my_library.

I checked the my_library.pom and found that facebook-android-sdk was listed in dependencies field. Anyone can help, please!

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle? how do you add the library in the project?

Comment: If your library produces an aar file, you need to add `transitive=true` when adding the library as a dependency.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. 
@RaGe, "transitive=true" not worked for me. Did you get the solution @user2575001?

Comment: @karthi is you dependency listed in the pom file accompanying the aar?

Comment: @Rage I am using gradle and I have added the dependency in build.gradle. I have AAR "A". I used the library "A" in "B". Then I used the library "B" in the another App. I can access the classes from "B" and can't from "A". I did use the above solution. But not working. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user2575001 did you or any other people find the solution yet